# Different ways to pivot a column in Oracle SQL and apply format masks

Tags: sql, oracle, format, pivot

I work on SQL Developer and BIRT Viewer and I get this error when applying the format mask '999G999G999G999G999G999G990':

```
ORA-01722: μη αποδεκτός αριθμός
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.
```

The query:

```
select
        *
    from

(   select  pc.description production_category,
                decode(pph.allocation,1,'GR-70B',2,'BG',3,'GR-70A',4,'GR-70Δ',6,'UK',8,'USA-KY',9,'USA-OR') alloc,   
          to_number(to_char(sum(ppd.pcs),'999G999G999G999G999G999G990')) pcs
        
from prd_production_hd pph,
            prd_production_details ppd,
            prod_categories pc
        where pph.id = ppd.production_id
        and ppd.prd_category_id in (14,15,16,17,18,20,21,51,52,56)
        and ppd.pcs is not null
        and ppd.prd_category_id = pc.id
        and pph.prod_date = :P_DATE
        group by pc.description,pph.allocation
        )

    pivot (
        sum(pcs)
        for alloc in ('GR-70B' GR_70Β, 'BG' BG, 'GR-70A' GR_70Α, 'GR-70Δ' GR_70Δ,'UK' UK,'USA-KY' USA_KY,'USA-OR' USA_OR)
    )`
```

Is there an alternative way to apply the format mask?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to want to aggregate and then format the number:

```sql
SELECT production_category,
       TO_CHAR(GR_70Β,'999G999G999G999G999G999G990') AS GR_70B,
       TO_CHAR(BG,    '999G999G999G999G999G999G990') AS BG,
       TO_CHAR(GR_70Α,'999G999G999G999G999G999G990') AS GR_70Α,
       TO_CHAR(GR_70Δ,'999G999G999G999G999G999G990') AS GR_70Δ,
       TO_CHAR(UK,    '999G999G999G999G999G999G990') AS UK,
       TO_CHAR(USA_KY,'999G999G999G999G999G999G990') AS USA_KY,
       TO_CHAR(USA_OR,'999G999G999G999G999G999G990') AS USA_OR
FROM   (
  SELECT pc.description AS production_category,
         pph.allocation,
         ppd.pcs
  FROM   prd_production_hd pph
         INNER JOIN prd_production_details ppd
         ON pph.id = ppd.production_id
         INNER JOIN prod_categories pc
         ON ppd.prd_category_id = pc.id
  WHERE  ppd.prd_category_id in (14,15,16,17,18,20,21,51,52,56)
  AND    ppd.pcs is not null
  AND    pph.prod_date = :P_DATE
)
PIVOT (
  SUM(pcs)
  FOR allocation in (
    1 AS GR_70Β,
    2 AS BG,
    3 AS GR_70Α, 
    4 AS GR_70Δ,
    6 AS UK,
    8 AS USA_KY,
    9 AS USA_OR
  )
);
```

*Note: you do not need to `DECODE` the `allocation`s before `PIVOT`ing; you can do it in the `PIVOT`. You also do not need to aggregate twice; again, do it once in the `PIVOT`.*

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it, this is wrong:

```
to_number(to_char(sum(ppd.pcs),'999G999G999G999G999G999G990'))
```

Inside out:

- `sum(ppd.pcs)` results in `number` datatype value
- you applied `to_char` to that numeric value and provided format model (which is OK)
- but, then you're applying `to_number` to it - **why**? That's where you started!

Therefore:

- either remove both `to_number(to_char(` and leave `sum(ppd.pcs)`

  - and you'll have `number` as result, or
- remove `to_number(`

  - and you'll have a *string* as result

Comment: I tried using either to_char or to_number but I still get the same error. The problem is that the pivot clause will not work. 

And I can't leave it as sum(ppd.pcs) cause I need to apply the format mask, in that specific way. This query is used in BIRT to create a PDF along with 2 more similar queries. BIRT won't work with this format and I can't use case clause which does work with no problems.  

Do you need me to specify you something?? I also tried formatting on pivot but that didn't work out as well.

Comment: Have a look at MT0's answer, I hope it'll help.